# How do I prevent Layou pay from reloading on every click/page change?

Tags: reactjs, components, gatsby, href, gatsby-plugin

So I just started using Gatsby because Im creating a portfolio website for myself. Every time I click on the links in my navbar a new page renders, therefore re-rendering the Layout component inside those pages, but how do I prevent that form happening? I want the layout component to render once because I have animations on the title and icons. When I was watching a video on how to use Gatsby pages, it said to wrap the elements inside my pages in the  component so that the title and navbar can persist. But because I'm doing that the layout re-renders?

Layout Component

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import Links from "./Links";
import "/styles/styles.css";


function Layout ( {children}) {
  return (

    <section >
    <div className="layout">
      <div id="introduction">
        <h2 className="title">Hi! My name is</h2>
        <h1 id="name">ANGIE MATICORENA</h1>
        <h2 className="title">Full Stack Software Engineer</h2>
      </div>
        <Links/>
      </div>
      <div className="layout">
         <Navbar />
         <div id="container">
             {children}
         </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

Navbar

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "gatsby";

function Navbar() {

    return (
        <nav id="navbar" >
            <Link to="/" className="tabs">Home</Link>
            <Link to="/about" className="tabs">About Me</Link>
            <Link to="/projects" className="tabs">Projects</Link>
            <Link to="contactme" className="tabs">Contact Me</Link>
        </nav>
    )

}

export default Navbar;
```

Index Page

```
import React from "react";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import "/styles/styles.css";

function App () {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div id="introduction">
        <h3>Hello World</h3>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default App;
```

About Me Page

```
import React from "react";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";

function About() {
    return (
        <Layout>
         <h1>About Me</h1>
        </Layout>
    )
};

export default About;
```

Answer (score 0):

For preventing a component from being unmounted on page changes Gatsby exposes a Browser API called wrapPageElement:
[wrapPageElement docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/#wrapPageElement)

In the root of your project, you create a *gatsby-browser.js* file and use wrapPageElement. In your case it might look something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Layout from 'src/components/layout';
export const wrapPageElement = ({element, props}) => (
  <Layout {...props}>{element}</Layout>
);
```